Moment of inertia respect to arbitrary axis
I have a programm and want to "import" design of an object into this programm from solidworks in order to be able calculate moment of inertia respect to arbitrary axis. Is there any way to do this using API?
I think it is possible to separate object to a lot of blocks with volume dV using mesh of an object and then calculate moment using formula r²dm. But I want to know is there alternative ways and how better to accomplish this task.
